# Equidifferentiability and Taylor series expansions

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, equicontinuity

Suppose the sequence of vector valued functions $\{ {\bf f}_n \}$ are equidifferentiable at ${\bf x}_0$. In other words:

> $$\lim_{{\bf h} \to {\bf 0}} \max_n    \frac{\left\Vert {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0+{\bf h}) -  {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0) - \triangledown {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0) {\bf h}
>  \right\Vert}{\left\Vert {\bf h} \right\Vert} = 0$$

Suppose we have  ${\bf x}_n$ such that ${\bf x_n} \to {\bf x}_0$ as $n \to \infty$.

> **Question**. Is it true than we can then perform the following Taylor expansion
>
> $$   {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_n)  = {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0) +  \triangledown {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0) ({\bf x}_n - {\bf x}_0) + o({\bf x}_n - {\bf x}_0)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just follows from the rule $o(o(1)) = o(1)$. Denote

> $$r_n({\bf h}) =  \frac{\left\Vert {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0+{\bf h}) -  {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0) - \triangledown {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0) {\bf h}
>  \right\Vert}{\left\Vert {\bf h} \right\Vert} $$

Then, we have, from equidifferentiability,

> $$ \max_n  r_n({\bf h}) = o({\bf h})$$

Hence, for any ${\bf h} \to 0$,

> $$   {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0 + {\bf h})  = {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0) +  \triangledown {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0) {\bf h} + o({\bf h})$$

Replacing ${\bf h}$ by ${\bf x}_n -{\bf x}_0$ ,

> $$   {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_n)  = {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0) +  \triangledown {\bf f}_n({\bf x}_0) ({\bf x}_n - {\bf x}_0) + o({\bf x}_n - {\bf x}_0)$$